# fix google crawl 404 errors with laravel

Tags: laravel, seo, laravel-routing, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I've replaced lately an old website with a new one made with laravel. Now if i check google webmaster tools I have some 404 errors due of course to different URIs.
    Yesterday I fixed them with a simple redirect like

```
    Route::get('librerie_su_misura/librerie_su_misura.php', function(){ 
    return Redirect::to('librerie-su-misura', 301);
});
```

But this morning when i woke up i was thinking whether it will be ok for Google, or maybe it's a better approach to load the pages on the same old paths like

```
    Route::get('librerie_su_misura/librerie_su_misura.php', 'LibrerieController@index');
```

what's the best approach according to you? Of course i would like the old routes to be deleted some day, do you think the first approach can be ok for google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RFC2616, [section 10.3.2 301 Moved Permanently](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2):

> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new references returned by the server, where possible.

This is also [recommended practice from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en).